# Add cookie to response object inside a get request in node JS?

Tags: node.js, cookies, request

I am trying to add a cookie to the response object (res) inside a different get request. However, if I try the following it will give me an error where I cannot set headers after they are sent. I assume by calling "request" I send the header already, how can I achieve adding a cookie to the response object using data from the separate get request? The synchronous nature won't let me save the data outside of the get request either. I am using request module from npm btw, thank you.

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = 0
    var status = "Not currently logged in.";
    if (req.cookies.token !== undefined) {
      status = "Currently Logged in.";
    }
    if (req.cookies.email !== undefined) {
      request('https://localhost:44338/api/customer/' + req.cookies.email 
      {json: true}, (err, response, body) => {
        res.cookie('user', body[0].customerID, {maxAge: 9000000});
        //console.log(body);
      });
    }
    res.render('index', { title: 'Mighty Morphin Store', data: "", status: status});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to send your response in the callback function after setting cookies.

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = 0
    var status = "Not currently logged in.";
    if (req.cookies.token !== undefined) {
      status = "Currently Logged in.";
    }
    if (req.cookies.email !== undefined) {
      request('https://localhost:44338/api/customer/' + req.cookies.email 
      {json: true}, (err, response, body) => {
        res.cookie('user', body[0].customerID, {maxAge: 9000000});
        //console.log(body);
        res.render('index', { title: 'Mighty Morphin Store', data: "", status: status});
      });
    }

});
```